# How do I downgrade from a dedicated EC2 server to a default EC2 server in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, dedicated-server

I have created a dedicated server, but I need to change it into a default server in AWS. The bill has been racking up.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct way to change tenancy ( dedicated to default ); you need to take the AMI of the instance and relaunch it; but this time be sure that the tenancy is specified as `default`

If that doesn't work out, launch a new EC2 instance and migrate the data and terminate the old instance.